# Puppeteer: Unable to select non-anchor element

Tags: puppeteer

[image]

The space between the two horizontal rules is clickable, although there is no `a` tag to target a selector onto. I have tried probably 10 selectors at this point and none have been successful. I would like any suggestions you may have for targeting difficult selectors for a click.

Patterns I have tried:

```
const clickTarget = await page.waitForSelector(selector, {timeout: 0});
await clickTarget.click();

// alternatively
await page.waitForNavigation("load");
const clickTarget = await page.$(selector);
await clickTarget.click();
```

Some selectors used (all have failed)

```
"#StoreListItemContainer"
"p[id=StoresListItem-LabelOnHover]"
"div.Polaris-ResourceItem_Content"
"div#SeanDezoysa"
```

The error message

```
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null

      42 |       
      43 |       const devStoreLink = await page.$(".Polaris-ResourceItem__Content");
    > 44 |       await devStoreLink.click();
         |                         ^
```

Comment: You can use waitForSelector as I answered in your previous question.

Comment: Did you see my first pattern example? That is the one I'm using the most; it's not fixing the issue though